# Rails change application.js to application.js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm liking coffee!

Is there any reason I can't change my application.js file to application.js.coffee?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I just tried changing it and got this error (along with 58 other errors):
reserved word "function" on line 11
  (in /Users/burtondav/sites/requestsys/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)

Comment: actually you can, why do you think you can't?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Rails.  The application.js file has always been without the .coffee -->  I never knew why.

Comment: try changing js comments // to coffee comments # (hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to rename a manifest file . It is a vital part of the asset-pipeline . It has a special purpose : to manage javasript assets . If you take a look at the default structure of the `application.js` file , you'll notice it is rather unusual . I think the better way to write in coffeescript is to create files with pieces of code and put them in related `javascripts` assets folders . Try to create a new js.coffee file and place it in `app/assets/javascripts` directory . In most usual cases it will be ready to operate . If you are about to translate javasript -> coffeescript , I guess you are aware of [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) tool.